# Compiled TypeScript to a bundle.. now what?

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs, brunch

When using Typescript `--outFile`, or with a build tool like brunch I get a transpiled and concatenated JavaScript file with all of my modules in it.

Something like:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var globals = typeof window === 'undefined' ? global : window;
  if (typeof globals.require === 'function') return;

  var modules = {};
  var cache = {};
  var aliases = {};
  var has = ({}).hasOwnProperty;

  var expRe = /^\.\.?(\/|$)/;
  var expand = function(root, name) {
    var results = [], part;
    var parts = (expRe.test(name) ? root + '/' + name : name).split('/');
    for (var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
      part = parts[i];
      if (part === '..') {
        results.pop();
      } else if (part !== '.' && part !== '') {
        results.push(part);
      }
    }
    return results.join('/');
  };

  var dirname = function(path) {
    return path.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
  };

  var localRequire = function(path) {
    return function expanded(name) {
      var absolute = expand(dirname(path), name);
      return globals.require(absolute, path);
    };
  };

  var initModule = function(name, definition) {
    var module = {id: name, exports: {}};
    cache[name] = module;
    definition(module.exports, localRequire(name), module);
    return module.exports;
  };

  var expandAlias = function(name) {
    return aliases[name] ? expandAlias(aliases[name]) : name;
  };

  var require = function(name, loaderPath) {
    if (loaderPath == null) loaderPath = '/';
    var path = expandAlias(name);

    if (has.call(cache, path)) return cache[path].exports;
    if (has.call(modules, path)) return initModule(path, modules[path]);

    throw new Error('Cannot find module "' + name + '" from ' + '"' + loaderPath + '"');
  };

  require.alias = function(from, to) {
    aliases[to] = from;
  };

  require.reset = function() {
    modules = {};
    cache = {};
    aliases = {};
  };

  var extRe = /\.[^.\/]+$/;
  var indexRe = /\/index(\.[^\/]+)?$/;
  var addExtensions = function(bundle) {
    var alias = bundle;
    while (extRe.test(alias)) {
      alias = alias.replace(extRe, '');
      if (!has.call(aliases, alias) || aliases[alias].replace(extRe, '') === alias + '/index' || bundle === alias + '.js') {
        aliases[alias] = bundle;
      }
    }

    if (indexRe.test(bundle)) {
      var iAlias = bundle.replace(indexRe, '');
      if (!has.call(aliases, iAlias)) {
        aliases[iAlias] = bundle;
      }
    }
  };

  require.register = require.define = function(bundle, fn) {
    if (typeof bundle === 'object') {
      for (var key in bundle) {
        if (has.call(bundle, key)) {
          require.register(key, bundle[key]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      modules[bundle] = fn;
      delete cache[bundle];
      addExtensions(bundle);
    }
  };

  require.list = function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var item in modules) {
      if (has.call(modules, item)) {
        result.push(item);
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  require.brunch = true;
  require._cache = cache;
  globals.require = require;
})();
require.register("scripts/main.ts", function(exports, require, module) {
System.register(['./ranger'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var ranger_1;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (ranger_1_1) {
                ranger_1 = ranger_1_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            console.log(ranger_1.default.name);
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
});

;require.register("scripts/ranger.ts", function(exports, require, module) {
System.register([], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            exports_1("default",{
                name: 'I am a ranger!'
            });
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=ranger.js.map
});

;
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

Now.. how am I supposed to use this? I've compiled everything here with SystemJS but I could use commonjs or amd too. I tried using System.JS and importing something.. but that is the wall I run into. The modules have all already been imported. I just need to select one (say a main entry module) and execute it. I've read things about these tools (might?) include "micro-loaders" to do just this, but haven't found any examples that show how they are actually used.

Comment: Random: I see I'm not the only one who constantly mis-types "transpiled" as "transpired". :)

Comment: @Aaron it was auto-correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

Then you load your modules from that file using a tool like, SystemJS or RequireJS..

In your index.html file, you could write like so:

```
<script src="path/to/libs/requirejs/require.js" data-main="myCompiledJSFile"></script>
```

Note the myCompiledJSFile is the complete file you transpired using TypeScript.

Comment: But isn't `data-main` supposed to point a "main" module? The one that kicks everything off? myCompiledJSFile is just a concatenation of all my modules.